# Which parameter I pass to CGimage for Height n Width

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have one issue regarding UIImageView and UIImage I get confuse on 1 thing ie My **" UIImageView Height = 759 and Width = 748"** and I am downloading the images from server that Height and width is so so greater Such as **"Image Height = 2048 and Width = 2500"**

so I am little bit confuse while rendering the image on UIImageView what I pass the parameter into CGImage

I am passing the parameter to the CGImage as below

```
CGImage _bitmap = new CGImage (2048 , 2500 , 8 , 32 , 2048 * 4 , _colorSpace , CGBitmapFlag.ByteOrderDefault , null, true , CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
```

which type  of parameter I pass in CGImage() means I pass Image parameter or UIImageView parameter to CGImage so that my Image will render properly into UIImaeView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should bother using `CGImage` at all (unless you are specifically having memory issues).

Just do this:

```
UIImage yourImage;
//Download from your server here (I can fill it in if needed)
UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(new Frame(0, 0, 748, 759)); //This can also be setup in a XIB file
imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
imageView.Image = yourImage;
```

Play around with the content mode setting to get exactly what you need.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) is a link for content mode.

Comment: Thanks for ur rlpy I know about the content mode property but its not work image not fit to UIImageVIew

Comment: What happens when you try this approach?  What does the screen look like, can you post a screen shot?  This approach should work for you.

Comment: why not but check this link so that you'll find out the screen shots:-http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/How-to-display-12-bit-images-in-UIImageView-td4656427.html

Comment: Those aren't screenshots of what it looks like using my approach.  You are still using `CGImage` there.  Does it look exactly the same?